# Tinymce - want contents unmodifiable but formattable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

There is plugin called **uneditable** content in tinymce, but we can still delete/remove the content and it is not formattable even. Is there any plugin through which I can achieve following:

Contents are uneditable, for instance if the content is

```
     uneditablecontent
```

the value of content should persist througout(nobody can add/update/delete the content).
But I should be able to add various formatting effects like bold, alignments, change font size etc.

Any other opensource plugins with such features are also welcomed.
I want to use such feature to format contents of *td* within table.

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking is even possible, when you format you text you are changing your underlying content with all the html tags you chose , maybe you could check this in your script if you are using php, there is function named strip_tags which will get rid of the html tags, having this you can compare the remaining text after strip_tags() with your old text to check if the text has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write/find your own implementation of this. There is no core function of TinyMCE that can accomplish what you're asking - the `noneditable` plugin is probably the closest thing you'll be able to find for this.